# mod_rewrite - I'm in need of a very simple example to redirect urls internally

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm sure this is simple, but all the examples I'm finding make it look terribly complex.

I have a local web server running as a development server (`http://localhost:8080`), and I have another web server running (`http://nameofnetworkmachine:80`). I need to figure out how to interenally route all the traffic from `nameofnetworkmachine:80` to `localhost:8080`.

I have included the following code at the bottom of my httpd.conf file in apache2:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^/$  localhost:8080/ [PT]
```

but no redirects occur.

Does anyone have any idea what the best way to do this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the webroot of `nameofnetworkmachine`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhostrealname:8080
```